Copiar enlace a portapapeles cuando es una lista
He generado un codigo para que copie el contenido de un input y me muestre la notificacion sin problema. Al ejecutar el programa y hacer click en el boton copy-btn se ejecuta la accion onclick y me copia el contenido de la url, pero al mostrar mas de un dato en la lista, cuando hago click en el boton del segundo o tercer contenido solo me copia el url de la primera fila. Espero puedan ayudarme


function copyLink() {
    const textToCopy = document.getElementById().textContent;
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(textToCopy)
        .then(() => {
            showNotification();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error copying text to clipboard:", error);
        });
}

function showNotification() {
    const notification = document.getElementById("notification");
    notification.style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(() => {
        notification.style.display = "none";
    }, 2000); 
}
<div class="container">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="card gradient-card2 mb-3">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">                    
                    <div class="col-md-8">                        
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <h6 class="mb-0">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nombre_Mascota)</h6>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6 text-secondary">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nombre_Mascota)</div>
                        </div>
                        <hr />                        
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <h6 class="mb-0">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Edad)</h6>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6 text-secondary">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Edad)</div>
                        </div>
                        <hr />
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <h6 class="mb-0">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Color)</h6>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6 text-secondary">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Color)</div>
                        </div>                       
                        <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                             <h6 class="mb-0">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Url)</h6>
                         </div>
                         <div class="col-sm-6 text-secondary">
                             <span id="url">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Url)</span>
                             <div id="notification" class="alert alert-success" style="display: none;">Enlace copiado al portapapeles!</div>
                        </div>
                       <div class="col-sm-2">
                           <button class="btn btn-link" id="copy-btn" onclick="copyLink()">Copy Link</button>
                        </div>                            
                     </div>                         
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    
</div>




Estas repitiendo las id, estos deben ser únicos, además en tu función de copiar ni siquiera la usas const textToCopy = document.getElementById(/* Aquí falta algo */).textContent;.  Por otro lado, las preguntas debes dedicarle más trabajo a tu pregunta, ayuda a que te ayuden. Porque tu error es 100% del cliente, entonces en tu código de ejemplo no tiene que existir código de servidor. Debes generar un [MCVE] que permita visualizar claramente el problema que describes y así facilitar la labor de alguien que decida ayudarte
